# how to delete fk children in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I would like to delete the ICollection PriceBreaks from Product.

I'm using the following method. However they dont seem to delete. What am i missing. 
 When i step thru. i notice that "product.PriceBreaks.Clear();" doesn't actually clear the items. Do i need to flush or something?

public void RemovePriceBreak(int productId)
{

```
using (ISession session = EStore.Domain.Helpers.NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var product = session.Get<Product>(productId); 
   // i can see 20 PriceBreak records, tho nh prof saids PriceBreak table hasn't been hit
    product.PriceBreaks.Clear();
    session.SaveOrUpdate(product);
    transaction.Commit(); // PriceBreak table is hit here with select statement, no delete?
}
```

}

Here are my hbm files

```
  <class name="Product" table="Products">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32" column="Id" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="CompanyId" column="CompanyId" type="Int32" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Name" column="Name"/>
    <set name="PriceBreaks" table="PriceBreaks" generic="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" >
      <key column="ProductId" />
      <one-to-many class="EStore.Domain.Model.PriceBreak, EStore.Domain" />
    </set>    
  </class>



<class name="PriceBreak" table="PriceBreaks">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32" column="Id" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id> 
    <many-to-one name="Product" column="ProductId"  not-null="true"  class="EStore.Domain.Model.Product, EStore.Domain" />    
  </class>
```

My Entities

```
 public class Product
    {

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PriceBreak> PriceBreaks { get; set; }
        public virtual void AddPriceBreak(PriceBreak priceBreak)
        {
            priceBreak.Product = this;
            PriceBreaks.Add(priceBreak);
        }
    }




 public class PriceBreak
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }  
    }
```

Here is the sql from nhprof

// 
SELECT product0_.Id               as Id0_0_
FROM   Products product0_
WHERE  product0_.Id = 23 /* @p0 */

and then

SELECT pricebreak0_.ProductId        as ProductId1_,
       pricebreak0_.Id               as Id1_,
       pricebreak0_.Id               as Id1_0_,
       pricebreak0_.ProductId        as ProductId1_0_,
FROM   PriceBreaks pricebreak0_
WHERE  pricebreak0_.ProductId = 23 /* @p0 */

there is no update or select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product probably needs to be associated with that session. It looks like you are trying to save a detached object. Which means there is no session to track that call to clear the PriceBreaks. Change it to this...

```
public void RemovePriceBreak(int productId)
{

    using (ISession session = EStore.Domain.Helpers.NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var product = session.Get<Product>(productId);
        product.PriceBreaks.Clear();
        session.SaveOrUpdate(product);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

or move the session and transaction management further up. Which would basically eliminate the need for this method.

Comment: hmm, gave this a go. Still no joy. I've updated the question above with the new method.

Comment: Can you show us your entities and how you manage relationship between these two. It looks like you are exposing you collection as a list. You might want to re-think that. What would for example product.PriceBreaks[0].product = someOtherProduct mean?

Comment: epitka, i've added the entites. What alternative to list do you suggest.

Comment: Are you sure PriceBreaks exist for the product? Is any SQL being executed? Maybe try changing key property to `<key column="ProductId" not-null="true" />` or it might be mismatch between `set` and `ICollection`. I generally use `bag` and `IList` or `set` and `Iesi.Collections.HashedSet`

Comment: thanks dotjoe really helpful! so looking in nhprof i see some interesting results ( see comments in RemovePriceBreak method above. I've changed ICollection to ISet. There are definately results in the product.PriceBreak so i didn't change the key.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't issue the deletes until the commit, so that is normal. NH will keep track of all the needed db operations and wait for a flush, commit, or possibly another query to trigger the execution. When you say "PriceBreak table is hit", what is the generated SQL?

Comment: @frosty also, like @mathieu said, you don't need the cascade="all" on the PriceBreak side. This might be causing unknown behavior because both sides want to cascade operations to each other.

Comment: i've included the sql, can you clarify, are my cascade settings correct above

Comment: hmm, I think when you `Clear()` the collection, that will result in the collection being fetched (via the 2nd select). It needs to be fetched so the individual deletes can be issued. I think there are ways to make Clear do a batch delete. Either way, something else is wrong. How do you initialize the ISet? In the Product constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting the cascade="all" on the PriceBreak side ?

Have you tried using session.Save() instead of SaveOrUpdate() ?

Comment: 1) I've removed cascade="all" from priceBreak in product.hmb. I edit the above to how i have it now. 
2) do you  mean session.Save